# Matlab,DSP: How to check if an array has hermitian symmetry

Tags: matlab, matrix, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I have a rather large piece of code at the end of which I need to apply ifft to an array `ZF`. `ZF` is the fft of the columns of a matrix `Z`.

The problem is, the ifft turns out to be a complex double array (which it shouldn't if I did everything correctly) so I need a debugging tool to check at which point of the numerous manipulations I performed on the original DFT I lost the Hermitian Symmetry.

The array is a double `1024x1376`

my attempt at this is:

```
for i=2:N/2
    Herm=ZF(i,:)+ZF(N-i+2,:);
end
```

`N=1024` is the number of rows and if Herm is purely real then I have the Symmetry.

Any thoughts? I'm still on the first month of MATLAB so if I'm way off feel free to tell me.

Comment: Post an example (short) input array that causes the problem

Comment: [`issymmetric`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/issymmetric.html?refresh=true) can help you to check whether a matrix is symmetric or skew-symmetric. [`ishermitian`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ishermitian.html) can tell you if its is hermitian or skew-hermitian.

Comment: Note that Hermitian symmetry is a very fragile concept when you manipulate arrays of floating-point numbers. Depending on how you construct your matrix, it may be very close to Hermitian, but not exactly. Sadly, even the built-in `ishermitian` (as suggested by @ParagS.Chandakkar) isn't numerically robust at all, in this case, because it checks for *exact* equality between a matrix of floats and its conjugate transpose, and testing for exact equality is hardly ever a good idea with floats. Instead, you may want to check for approximate equality.